# Generate List for Postgresql ARRAY column when using jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

By default, for a Postgresql ARRAY column like `varchar[]`, jOOQ generates a corresponding array field, `String[]` in this case.

Is there a way to have jOOQ generate a `List<String>` instead?

Answer (score 2):

This is supported out-of-the-box, but you do need to specify [a Forced Type](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/) for the type or column.

Below is an example using the [etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin), jOOQ 3.18+ and Kotlin Gradle syntax:

```kotlin
jooqConfiguration.apply {
  generator.apply {
    database.apply {
      forcedTypes.add(
        ForcedType().apply {
          // Or kotlin.collections.(Mutable)List<String> when using Kotlin
          userType = "java.util.List<String>"
          isAutoConverter = true
          includeTypes = "_varchar"
          // You can also use includeExpression instead or in addition,
          // to limit it to specific columns
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

When using `includeTypes`, it needs to match the database type exactly as reported. [For Postgresql `varchar[]`, this is `_varchar`](https://dbfiddle.uk/4a3yYtHA)